# Mono.Cecil TypeReference to Type?

Tags: c#, mono, mono.cecil

Is there anyways to go from a TypeReference in Mono.Cecil to a Type?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In terms of "what's in the box" you can only have it the other way round, using the `ModuleDefinition.Import`  API.

To go from a `TypeReference` to a `System.Type` you will need to manually look it up using Reflection and the `AssemblyQualifiedName`. Be aware that Cecil uses IL conventions to escape nested classes etc, so you need to apply some manual correction.

If you only want to resolve non-generic, non-nested types you should be fine though.

To go from a `TypeReference` to a `TypeDefition` (if that's what you meant) you need to to `TypeReference.Resolve();`

---

Requested Code Sample:

```
TypeReference tr = ... 
Type.GetType(tr.FullName + ", " + tr.Module.Assembly.FullName); 
// will look up in all assemnblies loaded into the current appDomain and fire the AppDomain.Resolve event if no Type could be found
```

The conventions used in Reflection are explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1.aspx), for Cecils conventions consult the Cecil Source Code.

Comment: Also note that Mono.Cecil is NOT built over System.Reflection (being an independent library), that means that there's no direct way to convert them to each other. You should still be able to do that, but it won't look nice.

Comment: So how with reflection would I lookup the type? And do you have an example of a reflection nested type and a cecil nested type?

Comment: Instead of manually adding ", ", you can use Assembly.CreateQualifiedName(tr.Module.Assembly.FullName, tr.FullName).

Comment: provided code doesn't work for generic types because Cecil uses "ClassName<gen_arg_0, ...>" notation when .Net Reflection expects "ClassName[[gen_arg_0],...] notation.

Comment: @AndyT: Yes, that's just one of the many cases where the notation differs. Thanks for your sample.

Comment: Is there a way to go in the opposite direction? From System.Type to Mono.Cecil.TypeDefinition?

Comment: @JohnZabroski you have to do something like this:
`var assemblyDefinition = AssemblyDefinition.ReadAssembly(type.Assembly.Location,params);
var resolverType = assemblyDefinition.MainModule.Types.SingleOrDefault(t=>t.Name == type.Name);`

Comment: Yes, i ended up with that

Answer (score 2):

For generic types you need something like this:

```
    public static Type GetMonoType(this TypeReference type)
    {
        return Type.GetType(type.GetReflectionName(), true);
    }

    private static string GetReflectionName(this TypeReference type)
    {
        if (type.IsGenericInstance)
        {
            var genericInstance = (GenericInstanceType)type;
            return string.Format("{0}.{1}[{2}]", genericInstance.Namespace, type.Name, String.Join(",", genericInstance.GenericArguments.Select(p => p.GetReflectionName()).ToArray()));
        }
        return type.FullName;
    }
```

Please note this code doesn't handle nested types, please check @JohannesRudolph answer for this